# How to efficiently add the entire English dictionary to a trie data structure

Tags: data-structures

Simply put I want to check if a specified word exists or not.

The lookup needs to be very fast which is why I decided to store the dictionary in a trie. So far so good! My trie works without issues. The problem is filling the trie with a dictionary. What I'm currently doing is looping through every line of a plain text file that is the dictionary and adding each word to my trie.

This is understandably so an extremely slow process. The file contains just about 120 000 lines. If anyone could point me in the right direction for what I could do it would be much appreciated!

This is how I add words to the trie (in Boo):

```
trie = Trie()

saol = Resources.Load("saol") as TextAsset
text = saol.text.Split(char('\n'))

for new_word in text:
    trie.Add(new_word)
```

And this is my trie (in C#):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TrieNode {
    public char letter;
    public bool word;
    public Dictionary<char, TrieNode> child;

    public TrieNode(char letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.word = false;
        this.child = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();
    }
}

public class Trie {
    private TrieNode root;

    public Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode(' ');
    }

    public void Add(string word) {
        TrieNode node = root;
        bool found_letter;

        int c = 1;
        foreach (char letter in word) {
            found_letter = false;

            // if current letter is in child list, set current node and break loop
            foreach (var child in node.child) {
                if (letter == child.Key) {
                    node = child.Value;
                    found_letter = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if current letter is not in child list, add child node and set it as current node
            if (!found_letter) {
                TrieNode new_node = new TrieNode(letter);
                if (c == word.Length) new_node.word = true;
                node.child.Add(letter, new_node);
                node = node.child[letter];
            }

            c ++;
        }
    }

    public bool Find(string word) {
        TrieNode node = root;
        bool found_letter;

        int c = 1;
        foreach (char letter in word) {
            found_letter = false;

            // check if current letter is in child list
            foreach (var child in node.child) {
                if (letter == child.Key) {
                    node = child.Value;
                    found_letter = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (found_letter && node.word && c == word.Length) return true;
            else if (!found_letter) return false;

            c ++;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `Dictionary` rather than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Unless you need your word list to be ordered, a HashList/Dictionary is a better choice.

Comment: Like I said, the lookups need to be almost instant, hence the data structure. The trie isn't the problem, it's quickly filling it.

Comment: Have you considered serializing the trie after the initial data load and then deserializing at invocation time? Others have noted that a Dictionary or HashList would be better, do you have a good reason to not use those?

Comment: If I were to simply use a regular Dictionary I would still have the same problem.

Comment: @ChristianAndersson On average, HashTables/Dictionarys are *faster* than Tries.  Why would you think that your Trie lookups are going be significantly faster than your insertions?

Comment: Yes, but the initial data load takes forever. That's the problem. It takes maybe 10 minutes to go through all those lines. Ignore the trie, I could possibly optimize it somewhat, but even without doing anything looping through 120 000 lines of a string is way too slow.

Comment: @ChristianAndersson Unless you have an *extremely* slow file system, I doubt that that's your problem.  It's much more likely to be the memory and structuring overhead of your Trie. (Well, I guess it could be a BOO problem also, as I do not know anything about it)

Comment: I'm hardly an expert on any of this. But as I understood it the trie is the fastest way to find a word in a text. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ChristianAndersson Yes, that is wrong.  Generally, hashing is the fastest method of keyed lookup.  Tries do have the theoretically fastest *worst case* lookup times, because there is no variance in the lookup times, but hashes have the fastest *average* times.  There's a reason that hashing is used so widely in professional software, and that Tries are used so rarely by them.

Comment: No and yes. You gain in that there are no collisions, but performance assumes that you satisfy the constraint that you lookup is O(m) where m is key length. Since you're using Dictionaries to store the children, you hurt lookup performance.

Comment: You seem to want the best of everything.  Directory structures are optimized for fast look-ups at the expense of slower writes and updates.  Flat files offer lightning fast writes at the expense of slow reads. RDBMs typically try to land somewhere in the middle in order to provide a balance of write and read performance.  You say you want fast writes and fast reads ... but ... don't we all?

Comment: I guess I was misinformed then... Thanks for the input guys!

Comment: that said, Tries *do* have specific features that make them very attractive in some case: specifically, *ordering* and *prefix lookup*, which cannot be done easily or efficiently with hashing.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Prefix lookup is something that I am going to implement. So I think I'll stick with a trie after all...

Comment: What I've done is create a representation of the trie in a database (as triads) and just "fault in" the specific values as they are referenced.  Requires some thought, but works pretty efficiently and allows you to "pre-load" the database offline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you don't have any serious implementation problems, pay the price for populating the trie. After you've populated the trie serialize it to a file. For future needs, just load the serialized version. That should be faster that reconstructing the trie.

-- ADDED --

Looking closely at your `TrieNode` class, you may want to replacing the `Dictionary` you used for `child` with an array. You may consume more space, but have a faster lookup time.

Comment: As serialization was probably the answer I was looking for I'll mark this as answered. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Anything you do with CLI yourself will be slower then using the built-in functions**.
120k is not that much for a dictionary.

First thing I would do is fire up the code performance tool.

But just some wild guesses: You have a lot of function calls. Just starting with the Boo C# binding in a for loop. Try to pass the whole text block and tare it apart with C#.

Second, do not use a Dictionary. You waste just about as much resources with your code now as you would just using a Dictionary.

Third, sort the text before you go inserting - you can probably make some optimizations that way. Maybe just construct a suffix table.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll look more closely into suffix tables.